# React Native Firebase signOut()

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, firebase-authentication

Simple question on Firebase and react native - all of the docs I see state to sign out a user it is simply:

```
firebase.auth().signOut()
```

This seems too simple. How does it know which user to sign out? Do I need to work with `getCurrentUser()` or `getInstance()` to be able to sign out the appropriate user? I am not seeing much documentation on this.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#signOut()

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/auth/phone-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can only have one user signed in at a time, signOut always affects just the one current user.  It is really just that simple.  All it has to do is delete the user's auth token.

Answer (score 1):

It's internal to Firebase. There is only one active user, the one returned by currentUser. signOut will logout that user.

Comment: so are you saying I need to utilize "currentUser()" or can I just do what the docs state with: `signOut = () => {firebase.auth().signOut();}`